# cannot link privileged user error

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, plsql, database-administration

Im trying to copy the objects from one schema to another in aws RDS instance.Below are the steps which i used.

```
create user target_usr identified by target_usr;
  GRANT CREATE JOB TO target_usr;
  GRANT CREATE TYPE TO target_usr;
  GRANT CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TO target_usr;
  GRANT CREATE ANY TRIGGER TO target_usr;
  GRANT CREATE TRIGGER TO target_usr;
  GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO target_usr;
  GRANT CREATE DATABASE LINK TO target_usr;
  GRANT CREATE SEQUENCE TO target_usr;
  GRANT CREATE VIEW TO target_usr;
  GRANT CREATE SYNONYM TO target_usr;
  GRANT CREATE TABLE TO target_usr;
  GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO target_usr;
  GRANT ALTER SESSION TO target_usr;
  GRANT CREATE SESSION TO target_usr;
```

the source schema already exists and pretty much same as target_usr;
Now the public db link created

```
CREATE public DATABASE LINK "dblink"   CONNECT TO source_usr IDENTIFIED BY <>   USING '<tns entry of aws rds instance';
```

i have tested the db link using a sample select query and the result returned as expected, so there is no problem in db link.

When i tried to execute the below datapump, im getting error like.

```
impdp superuser/sppwd@sourcetns schemas=source_usr directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR network_link=dblink remap_schema=source_usr:target_usr logfile=DATA_PUMP_DIR:SCOTT_NEW.log
```

and im getting below error

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-31631: privileges are required
ORA-39149: cannot link privileged user to non-privileged user
```

I have searched google a lot, but didnt get much for what i needed.Can you please help

Answer (score 0):

See Oracle support document ID 351598.1. The user specified in the database link has insufficient privileges to perform the export. Either grant that user the necessary privileges, or create and use a different database link utilizing a user that does have sufficient authority on the remote database.

Comment: But The user has necessary privileges and it was not working